# Prolog Predicate Help: Delete Number N times from List

Tags: list, prolog

Question: `deleteNum(+Element, +List, -NewList, +NumToDelete)` takes a list, an element, and the number of elements to delete from the `List`.  The `NewList` should be the original `List` minus `NumToDelete` `Elements`.  It does not matter which instances of the element get deleted, and no alternate answers should be given.  For example,

Example:

```
?- deleteNum(3, [2,3,5,4,3,3], NewList, 2).
NewList = [2,5,4,3]
```

This is the code I tried, but it kept returning false when I attempted the example above. I'm not sure why.

```
deleteNum(_, [],[], 0).
deleteNum(X, [X|T], T, 0).
deleteNum(X, [H|T], [H|T1], Num):- 
     Num1 is Num - 1, 
     deleteNum(X, T, T1, Num1).
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up two cases with this predicate:

```
deleteNum(X, [H|T], [H|T1], Num):- 
     Num1 is Num - 1, 
     deleteNum(X, T, T1, Num1).
```

It's not removing `X` yet it's still reducing `Num`.

Here's a couple of ways to do what you want:

```
deleteNum(_, L, L, 0).
deleteNum(X, [H|T], [H|T1], Num) :-
    X \= H,
    deleteNum(X, T, T1, Num).
    deleteNum(X, [X|T], T1, Num):- 
Num1 is Num - 1, 
    deleteNum(X, T, T1, Num1).
```

Or:

```
deleteNum(_, L, L, 0).
deleteNum(X, [X|T], T1, Num):- 
    !,
    Num1 is Num - 1, 
    deleteNum(X, T, T1, Num1).
deleteNum(X, [H|T], [H|T1], Num) :-
    deleteNum(X, T, T1, Num).
```

It depends if you like `!` or not.

Both succeed on `?- deleteNum(3, [2,3,5,4,3,3], NewList, 2), write(NewList), nl.` and unify `NewList` to `[2, 5, 4, 3]`.

Please keep in mind that Prolog doesn't return anything. It just succeeds or fails. Along the way it just tries to unify variables in order to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer but a debugging aid that would not fit a comment.**

We can define a property that your predicate **must** satisfy:

```
property(Element, List, NewList, Times) :-
    % first we call the predicate being tested ...
    deleteNum(Element, List, NewList, Times),
    % ... and then check the results
    findall(Element, between(1,Times,_), Elements),
    append(NewList, Elements, AllElements),
    msort(List, Sorted),
    msort(AllElements, Sorted).
```

I.e. we can recover all elements from the original list from `Element`, `NewList`, and `Times`. This property allows us to use *property-based testing*  to test your predicate. Using the property-based testing support provide by Logtalk's `lgtunit` tool QuickCheck implementation (which you can run in most Prolog systems) we get:

```
?- {lgtunit(loader)}.
...

?- lgtunit::quick_check(property(+between(integer,1,10), +list(integer,1,10), -list(integer,1,10), +between(integer,1,10))).
*     quick check test failure (at test 1 after 0 shrinks):
*       property(1,[],A,1)
*     starting seed: seed(3172,9814,20125)
false.
```

The failure prints a counter-example where your predicate fails: `property(1,[],A,1)`, i.e. `deleteNum(1,[],A,1)`. You can start by fixing this simple case. After the fix, you can run the `lgtunit::quick_check/1` query again to help locate more bugs if any remaining.